# How can I install my application as system application with using ADT tool

Tags: android

How can I install my application as system application with using ADT tool ?

Should I change some part?

Can you give answer as step by step ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  By default, when you deploy your app to a device, it is installed as an Application.

Comment: @Booger But in my case when I press run, emulator is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install from command line:

```
adb install YourApp.apk
```

From within Eclipse:
1. Right or double-click on your Project
2. Select Run as...
3. Android Application
4. If presented with a dialog to select an Emulator instance - select your target emulator

The docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: but I want physical device

Comment: Doesn't matter - this works for either a device or an emulator.  Don't forget to mark as correct.

Comment: But, I have not seen in package explorer .apk file. How can I generate ?

Comment: Dude, you need to read the docs.  You generate the apk when you build your Android project.  Check the link I included in my answer.  Trying not to be a jerk, but you need to help yourself.  This is very basic stuff.

Comment: I understand my computer does not see the device. What should I do ?

Comment: whenever I run above command, it waits the device. But, in computer directory of the my computer I can see the device folder, like usb folder.

Comment: You need to install the device driver for your device.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the Push command to send your Apk to system Directory

```
"adb push myApk.apk /system/app
```

but you will get an error

```
Not enough space left
```

although there will be some space 
the reason behind this is that this can only be possible on rooted devices to get access to "/system/" dir